# Blazor Server: Unique Id For Distinguish Clients

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Ok I'm trying to detect requests source in Custom AuthenticationStateProvider
So here is my tries:

- Session Id not working because every request retrieves tottally new id in same browser because of WebSocket
- Obvioisly HttpContext.Connection.Id is not working because it's changes for every refresh page
- builder.Services.AddSingleton is not working because its keeps data whole application's life cycle
- So as you know builder.Services.AddTransient and builder.Services.AddScoped also changing for every single request regardless of browser or pc
- Well I think HttpContext.Connection.Ip can not be used because of it uses same IP that PCs in same LAN

So how can I Distinguish which request belongs to which pc or browser
How can I Keep Logged in user In my way without using The Blazor's Authentication

Here is sample code

```
    /// <summary>
    /// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authenticationstateprovider-service
    /// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#implement-a-custom-authenticationstateprovider
    /// https://www.indie-dev.at/2020/04/06/custom-authentication-with-asp-net-core-3-1-blazor-server-side/
    /// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0
    /// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#session-state
    /// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#where-to-persist-state
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor context;
        static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ClaimsPrincipal> logins = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ClaimsPrincipal>();
        public CustomAuthStateProvider(IHttpContextAccessor context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {


            if (logins.TryGetValue(context.HttpContext.Session.Id, out var p))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(p)); // <---- The debugger never stops here becuse Session Id is changes for every reqquest
            }
            else
            {
                //it will return empty information in real application for force it login
                //return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()))); 

                //This block does not belong here, it will be populated on the Login page in the real application. For now I'm just running it here for testing
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "RandomId"), //It will ger user infos from our custom database. (No MS's Auth Database)
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "A")
                }, "Fake authentication type");

                var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                logins[context.HttpContext.Session.Id] = user;
                return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
            }
            



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usually, I answering my own question myself.
According to my impressions Blazor applications is created for managing all periods in a single window
I think the best solution is using cookies.
So here is my solution

1. Create a js file and add to header

---

```
createBrowserId();
function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
            end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    // because unescape has been deprecated, replaced with decodeURI
    //return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
function uuidv4() {
    return ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
        (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
    );
}

function createBrowserId() {
    var myCookie = getCookie("fbc-bw-id");

    if (myCookie == null) {
        var uid = uuidv4();
        document.cookie = "fbc-bw-id=" + uid;
        console.log("Yoktur: " + uid)
    }
    else {
        console.log("Vardir: " + myCookie);
    }
}
```

---

2. Create classes for managing Cookies

---

```
  class UserDataHolder
    {
        public DateTime Created { get; }
        public DateTime LastActionDate { get; private set; }
        public SysUser User { get; }

        public UserDataHolder(SysUser user)
        {
            Created = LastActionDate = DateTime.Now;
            User = user;
        }

        public void HadAction() => LastActionDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    class SessionAIUser
    {
        public string? UserId { get; }
        //public string? UserCreatedDate { get; }
        //public string? SessionId { get; }
        //public string? SessionCreatedDate { get; }
        //public string? SessionUpdatedDate { get; }

        public SessionAIUser(HttpContext? context)
        {
            if (context != null && context.Request != null && context.Request.Cookies != null && context.Request.Cookies.Any())
            {
                var c = context.Request.Cookies;
                if (c.TryGetValue("fbc-bw-id", out string? fbcid))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fbcid))
                    {

                        this.UserId = fbcid;

                        //add ip addr too when only cookie is working
                        try
                        {
                            String ip = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
                            {
                                this.UserId += ip;
                            }
                            //Console.WriteLine("ip:" + ip);
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }


    }

    public class UserSessionManager
    {
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserDataHolder> _users;
        private static DateTime lastPerodicalIdleChecked = DateTime.Now;
        private const long IDLE_TIME_LIMIT_SECONDS = 60 * 5;
        private HttpContext? context;
        private SessionAIUser aiData;
        private const string COOKIE_ERROR = "Bu uygulama çerezleri (cookies) kullanmaktadır. Eğer gizli (private) modda iseniz lütfen normal moda dönünüz, eğer çerezler kapalı ise lütfen açınız. Veya sayfayı yenileyerek tekrar deneyiniz.";

        static UserSessionManager()
        {
            _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserDataHolder>();
        }
        private static void PerodicalIdleCheck()
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - lastPerodicalIdleChecked).TotalSeconds > 60 * 3)
            {
                var dead = _users.Where(x =>

                 x.Value == null
                 || (x.Value != null && (DateTime.Now - x.Value.LastActionDate).TotalSeconds > IDLE_TIME_LIMIT_SECONDS)
                ).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

                if (dead.Any())
                {
                    dead.ForEach(x => _users.TryRemove(x, out UserDataHolder? mahmutHoca));
                }
            }
        }

        public UserSessionManager(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            this.context = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
            aiData = new SessionAIUser(this.context);
        }

        public SysUser? GetLoggedInUser()
        {
            PerodicalIdleCheck();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aiData.UserId) && _users.TryGetValue(aiData.UserId, out var userDataHolder))
            {
                if (userDataHolder != null)
                {
                    if ((DateTime.Now - userDataHolder.LastActionDate).TotalSeconds < IDLE_TIME_LIMIT_SECONDS && userDataHolder.User != null)
                    {
                        userDataHolder.HadAction();
                        return userDataHolder.User;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _users.TryRemove(aiData.UserId, out userDataHolder);
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public bool Login(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aiData.UserId))
            {
                using (var db = new DB())
                {
                    var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.SysUserName == userName && SysUser.ToMD5(password) == x.SysUserPassword).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        _users[aiData.UserId] = new UserDataHolder(user);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            throw new Exception(COOKIE_ERROR);
        }

        public void Logout()
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aiData.UserId))
            {
                _users.TryRemove(aiData.UserId, out var userDataHolder);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(COOKIE_ERROR);

            }

        }

    }
```

---

3. Add UserSessionManager class to services as Scope

---

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserSessionManager>();
...
```

---

4. Create a custom provider for managing session and add this provider too to Services.

---

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private HttpContext? context;
    private UserSessionManager userMgr;
    public CustomAuthStateProvider(IHttpContextAccessor context, UserSessionManager userMgr)
    {
        this.context = context.HttpContext;
        this.userMgr = userMgr;
    }
    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var lUser = userMgr.GetLoggedInUser();
        if (lUser != null)
        {
            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, lUser.SysUserName));
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, lUser.Name));
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, lUser.Surname));
            if (lUser.IsAdmin)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));

            }
            if (lUser.IsCanEditData)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "CanEditData"));
            }
            if (lUser.CariKartId != null)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim("CariKartId", "" + lUser.CariKartId));

            }
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Database uleyn");
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity())));
        }





    }
}
```

Adding

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
```

So this is my way of using the application with multiple tabs and multiple request  in same browser.

Comment: Ok wait now lets say that in the js we get a -1 for begin but in the if we then get a 0. end never gets declared outside its else. Wont this lead to an error?

Comment: in indexof method; -1 means there is no matched value; 0 means the matching occurs right at the beginning of the value.

Comment: But you define var end IN the else, but then use it outside the else, when you return the decodeURI.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to register a scoped service that generates a unique ID (or GUID). This worked for me, but for some reason on Blazor server side, it seems to create 3 or 4 new scoped instances, before settling on one. After that, the scoped service stays the same for a single session (until, for example, a refresh). In the example below I render the session ID on every page using the `MainLayout.razor`. You will see the ID change 3 or 4 times, but after that, it stays the same through page navigations, etc.

This was perfect for what I needed. I needed to dispatch a notification to every other user EXCEPT the current one. So I use a singleton service to dispatch and receive the notification, and a scoped service to determine the ID of the current session.

```cs
// SessionIdProvider.cs

public interface ISessionIdProvider
{
    Guid SessionId { get; }
}

public class SessionIdProvider : ISessionIdProvider
{
    public Guid SessionId { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

```cs
// Program.cs

builder.Services.AddScoped<ISessionIdProvider, SessionIdProvider>();
```

```html
// Shared/MainLayout.razor

<h1>Session @SessionIdProvider.SessionId</h1>

...

@code {
    [Inject]
    public ISessionIdProvider SessionIdProvider { get; set; }
}
```

The multiple IDs being generated at the start is not visible in this gif, because the framerate is too low (it happens VERY quickly).
[image: Unique session ID in Blazor demo]

More info on scoped services in Blazor: https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/dependency-lifetimes-and-scopes/scoped-dependencies/

Comment: Well this is not whay was requested at all. The questions was for a way to keep data persisting for a logged in user. So the Data must stay after refreshes